# Pico-SIM7080G hat detects network but can't connect

Tags: at-command, raspberry-pi-pico, sim-card, nb-iot

I'm using Waveshare pico-sim7080g hat, trying to connect my Pico to LTE. I'm using Waveshare's setup code (HTTP.py from https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Pico-SIM7080G-Cat-M/NB-IoT) but failing to connect, even though the output shows that it sees a connection. According to T-Mobile, this SIM card is active and set for NB-IoT.

I'm new to all of this, so any help on how to fix (or even debug) this would be *greatly* appreciated. Below is the output. Thank you in advance!

```
------SIM7080G is starting up, please wait------

AT
OK

------SIM7080G is ready------

ATE1
OK

Setting to NB-IoT mode:

AT+CFUN=0
+CPIN: NOT READY

OK

AT+CNMP=38
OK

AT+CMNB=2
OK

AT+CFUN=1
OK

+CPIN: READY

SMS Ready

AT+CNCFG=0,1,"fast.t-mobile.com"
OK

AT+CNACT=0,1
OK

+APP PDP: 0,DEACTIVE

AT+CNACT?
+CNACT: 0,0,"0.0.0.0"
+CNACT: 1,0,"0.0.0.0"
+CNACT: 2,0,"0.0.0.0"
+CNACT: 3,0,"0.0.0.0"
```

Comment: are you running this by typing each command or through some code you wrote? Your AT commands does not check whether the signal strength is good or not with AT+CSQ? nor on whether the module has registered to the network with AT+CEREG? If all those commands return good, you can then try to connect with the data network with AT+CNACT=0,1

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! AT+CSQ returned 31,99, so I do have a strong signal, and the inability to figure out the bit error rate is probably related to AT+CEREG? returning 0,3; looks like I was denied entry. Guess it's a t-mobile issue. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction!